# Firefox search engine for local google (.com.au)

Tags: firefox, search-engines, google-search

Is there a way to make my Firefox 3.5 "Google" search engine use google.com.au rather than google.com?

Ideally I'd like that change Ubiquity to do that as well.

Comment: By "google search engine" you mean the little box in the upper right corner, true ?

Comment: @Idigas Please stop joking. Being able to search from within address bar for a couple of years now there's no reason to use *the little box in the upper right corner*, true?

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, but actually, that box in the upper right is what I use and it is what I meant.

Comment: The upper right corner box is fantastic for non-google searches such as Wikipedia, YouTube, Amazon, eBay etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/search-engines.html?name=google&opensearch=yes) page when in Firefox. You'll find all the possible Google pages you might need, including the Australian version. When you find what you want, just click the link on that page. It will add the new search engines to the Firefox search box.

If you need to add a search engine to Firefox, IE 7/8 or Chrome, you can probably find it over on the [Mycroft Project](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/).

Comment: Just realized that this also works in Chrome. If you click a link on the page, it asks you if you want to add a new search engine.

Comment: No problem! The Mycroft Project works with Firefox, IE 7/8 and Chrome. If you need to add a search engine, just look for it there (http://mycroft.mozdev.org/)

Answer (score 2):

This was already answered, but you can also just create a bookmark to the Google Australia search url, and then use a keyword to access it from the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the current "Google" from  your list of search providers then open google.com.au.

The dropdown arrow should be highlighted. Open the list and at the bottom it should say "Add Google".

This will add the current (Australian) page.